# Null pointer expeception is showing while call a class function to another selenium class

Tags: java, selenium

I created a java class and written logic for password and confirm password in the class. while calling the class in another class by creating class object, it is showing null pointer exception.

```
public class Verify_password {
    WebDriver driver;
    String pwd = "password";
    String confirm_pwd = "password";
    String wrong_pwd="yogesh";
    public void password_match(){
        //Password = confirm password
        driver.findElement(By.id("encrypted_pwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("confirm_pwd")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("encrypted_pwd")).sendKeys(pwd);
        driver.findElement(By.id("confirm_pwd")).sendKeys(confirm_pwd);
        driver.findElement(By.id("submit-btn")).click();
        if(pwd ==confirm_pwd){
            System.out.println("Password Match");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Password doesn't Match");
        }
    }
```

Calling this class to another class by:

```
Verify_password password1 = new Verify_password();
password1.password_match1();
```

Can someone verify and confirm that is it okay or not?

Thanks

Comment: public void password_match() this is your method in the class. So I think it should be password1.password_match();

Comment: public void password_match1(){
  //password & conform password <8
  driver.findElement(By.id("encrypted_pwd")).sendKeys(wrong_pwd);
  driver.findElement(By.id("confirm_pwd")).sendKeys(wrong_pwd);
  driver.findElement(By.id("submit-btn")).click();
  String error_msg = driver.findElement(By.id("encrypted_pwd1")).getText();
  if(wrong_pwd.length() < 8){
   System.out.println(error_msg);

Comment: Please edit your post and update it and remove the comment above.

Comment: @YogeshTrivedi Please do not add code as a comment. As you can see, it's totally unreadable. Edit it into your question and format it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an instance of a driver before using `password_match1()` method, for example by creating a constructor of `Verify_password` and inside of it creating an instance of WebDriver class.

Additionally you should fix your class name to be compliant with the proper naming convention to `VerifyPassword`  or `PasswordVerifier`. You can also work on your method name, to be just: `match()` - after all you know from a class name, that it concerns password operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

First you have to get the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>current version</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>current version</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you have to initialize a instance of an driver for example a firefox driver:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

After that you have to call the site you want to test:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Now you could find the elements and do what you want to do:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id());
```

Additionally you should store the references of the elements in object. Every findElement call decrease the performance of your tests.

For more details see http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Still i am not getting the solution of the above problem, still getting Null pointer exception.